# Convert only date to Date and Time format in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to count data of each day from database using the for loop. Here, I don't know to get the begining of day (start from 12 am) and end of that day ( 12 pm) from value of only date. In below code startDate and endDate have only date value e.g. 2/11/2012.

```
for (DateTime dates = startDate; dates <= endDate; dates.AddDays(1))
{
    DateTime BeginingOfDay = begining of value variable dates; // 2/2/2012 00:00:00
    DateTime EndOfDay =  at end of value variable dates; // 2/2/2012 23:59:59
    int count = (from u in db.CDRs where (u.StartTime >= BeginingOfDay && u.StartTime <= EndOfDay) select u).Count();;

    dictionary.Add(dates.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), count);
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you calculate that in database completely instead of looping all days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is to use the right combination of lessthan/greaterthan operators with midnight on day `n`, and midnight on day `n+1`

so given a day, eg

```
var date = new Date(2012,8,24); // today
```

get midnight on that day (start of the day)

```
var start = new Date(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 0,0,0); // could also be date.Date
```

and to get midnight on the next day just add 1 day

```
var end = start.AddDays(1);
```

now use greater-than-or-equal-to for the start, and less-than for the end:

```
var inRange = x.StartTime>=start && x.EndTime<end
```

Put together into your example becomes:

```
for (DateTime dates = startDate; dates <= endDate; dates.AddDays(1))
{
    DateTime BeginingOfDay = new DateTime(dates.Year,dates.Month,dates.Day,0,0,0);
    DateTime EndOfDay =  BeginingOfDay.AddDays(1);
    int count = (from u in db.CDRs where (u.StartTime >= BeginingOfDay && u.StartTime < EndOfDay) select u).Count();;

    dictionary.Add(dates.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), count);
}
```

Comment: I have got problem in code. variable dates is not increased by AddDays(1) of for loop so , exception is thrown that dictionary have duplicate key. I have place break point in loop and it is not increasing date by one day. Would please tell me what may be mistake

Comment: @CodeManiac - you're for loops should have `dates = dates.AddDays(1)` at the end - otherwise the `dates` variable will not be incremented

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the results you want:

```
using(var dataContext = new YourDataContext())
{
    var dictionary = dataContext.CDRs.GroupBy(u => new
    {
        u.StartTime.Year,
        u.StartTime.Month,
        u.StartTime.Day
    })
    .Select(g => new{ Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(g => new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, g.Key.Day), g=>g.Count);
    return dictionary;
}
```